# Reports with field to be displayed at the bottom

Tags: reporting, custom, custom-report-type

There is requirement where I need to add a new field display called billing rate for a work under report which would be equal to multiple of average of the whole column multiplies by 40.

I have attached the screenshot for your reference.

[image]
Thanks